# Table of contents doesn't work

Tags: google-docs

I'm trying to add a table of contents to a document in Google Docs using **Insert > Table of contents** menu but it doesn't show any headings.

Here is a sample document:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jAH3pmeRT2kyqGPOeUA2QaiqEOISNKM678kDx7XeVoQ/edit?usp=sharing

It has a *Table of contents* on page 1, *Chapter 1* on p. 2 and *Chapter 2* on p. 3. Chapters **paragraph style** is set to **Title** but they don't appear in the table. This is how the table actually looks:

[image: Table of contents is broken]

I've pressed **refresh button** on the left many times - no effect.

I'm using web version of Google Docs. My browser is Google Chrome Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit). [Cleaning cookies](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/rMu56WsJqZ8) didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Chapter 1` and `Chapter 2` have style Title, change that to one of the Headings options (should be in the ribbon just under `Tools`) and then click on the icon shown at the left in your image.

Comment: This was not too obvious :)